# cannot create new user in openfire using smack-Android

Tags: java, android, openfire, smack

I am trying to create a new user using smack for the instant messaging app for android, the user will be stored in the openfire database but everytime, i am running it,the user record is not showing in openfire

create user activity

```
 private void setConnection() {

        // Create the configuration for this new connection

        //this function or code given in official documention give an error in openfire run locally to solve this error
        //first off firewall
        //then follow my steps

        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                InetAddress addr = null;
                try {
                    // inter your ip4address now checking it
                    addr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.23.150");
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                HostnameVerifier verifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                        return false;
                    }
                };
                DomainBareJid serviceName = null;
                try {
                    serviceName = JidCreate.domainBareFrom("localhost");
                } catch (XmppStringprepException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                        .setUsernameAndPassword("admin","kalaBOOK98")
                        .setPort(9090)
                        .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled)
                        .setXmppDomain(serviceName)
                        .setHostnameVerifier(verifier)
                        .setHostAddress(addr)
                        .setDebuggerEnabled(true)
                        .build();
                Log.v(TAG,"connection configured");
                mConnection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
                        //now send message and receive message code here
                        AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.getInstance(mConnection);
                        try {
                            Log.v(TAG,"Creating new user");
                            accountManager.createAccount(Localpart.from(userId),userPassword);
                        } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
                            Log.v(TAG,"Error in creating user"+e);
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
                            Log.v(TAG,"Error in creating user"+e);
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
                            Log.v(TAG,"Error in creating user"+e);
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            Log.v(TAG,"Error in creating user"+e);
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (XmppStringprepException e) {
                            Log.v(TAG,"Error in creating user"+e);
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

// Now we create the account:

// The account has been created, so we can now login

        }.start();
    }
```

Everytime i try to run it this log error shows up

Log

```
    2018-11-30 18:44:16.186 12186-12855/com.example.user.myapplication V/SignupActivity: connection configured
2018-11-30 18:44:16.216 12186-12855/com.example.user.myapplication V/SignupActivity: Creating new user
2018-11-30 18:44:16.218 12186-12855/com.example.user.myapplication V/SignupActivity: Error in creating userorg.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NotConnectedException: Client is not, or no longer, connected.
2018-11-30 18:44:16.218 12186-12855/com.example.user.myapplication W/System.err: org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NotConnectedException: Client is not, or no longer, connected.
2018-11-30 18:44:16.226 12186-12855/com.example.user.myapplication W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.throwNotConnectedExceptionIfAppropriate(XMPPTCPConnection.java:354)
2018-11-30 18:44:16.226 12186-12855/com.example.user.myapplication W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.sendStanza(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:670)
2018-11-30 18:44:16.227 12186-12855/com.example.user.myapplication W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.createStanzaCollectorAndSend(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:769)
2018-11-30 18:44:16.227 12186-12855/com.example.user.myapplication W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smackx.iqregister.AccountManager.createStanzaCollectorAndSend(AccountManager.java:370)
2018-11-30 18:44:16.227 12186-12855/com.example.user.myapplication W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smackx.iqregister.AccountManager.getRegistrationInfo(AccountManager.java:366)
2018-11-30 18:44:16.227 12186-12855/com.example.user.myapplication W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smackx.iqregister.AccountManager.getAccountAttributes(AccountManager.java:184)
2018-11-30 18:44:16.227 12186-12855/com.example.user.myapplication W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smackx.iqregister.AccountManager.createAccount(AccountManager.java:249)
2018-11-30 18:44:16.227 12186-12855/com.example.user.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.example.user.myapplication.Login.SignupActivity$3.run(SignupActivity.java:192)
```

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not working from long on smack and openfire but can you try my sample https://github.com/saveendhiman/XMPPSample_Studio

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the log, you must be connected to server for creating new user. there is a problem with your connection and you can't create user until reconnect be successful.
You can check your connection or authenticate state before create user by these methods:

```
connection.isAuthenticated()
connection.isConnected()
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
mConnection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
//now send message and receive message code here
AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.getInstance(mConnection);
try {
    accountManager.createAccount(Localpart.from(userId),userPassword);
} …
```

**After you created the connection instance, it is not connected.** That is why you get a **`NotConnectedException`** when you try to perform an operation which requires a connected connection. In order to create the account on your XMPP service, you first have to connect to service by calling

```
`mConnection.connect()`.
```